# Pig Input path to HDFS in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
grunt> ways = LOAD '/hdfs://localhsot:9000/pig/ldh.osm as (ways);
grunt> DUMP Ways;
```

Error:

```
Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:9000/pig/ldh/ldh.osm"
```

Output(s):

```
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/ways"
```

Counters:

```
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

Job DAG:

```
null


2016-06-19 14:31:41,604 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 
Failed!
```

Please provide a solution for this.
I think my input is not configured to hdfs in hadoop. Give solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. please spend some time to learn about SO and formatting before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

Schema of the file should be defined after 'AS' Keyword  alias are not allowed after the 'as' keyword in pig

```
grunt> ways  = load '/hdfs://localhsot:9000/pig/ldh.osm' as  (test1:chararray) ;
grunt> dump ways;
```

---

Ways and ways are Different.

Case Sensitivity -- 
The names (aliases) of relations and fields are case sensitive. The names of Pig Latin functions are case sensitive. The names of parameters and all other Pig Latin keywords are case insensitive. (LOAD, USING, AS, GROUP, BY, FOREACH, GENERATE, and DUMP are case insensitive)

Comment: Thanku very much for response.  Yes I have made changes. But it is not working and not getting any input file from HDFS. Please give me solution to correct this error.

Comment: what kind of data osm file contains

Comment: road data of any city with extension of .osm or .csv

Comment: load 'file.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (test1:type);